# Сколько бит информации несет сообщение?

Tags: информатика

> Есть два четырехгранника, на каждую грань которых нанесены цифры 1, 2, 3 и 4. При выбрасывании четырехгранник с равной вероятностью ложится на поверхность любой гранью. Оба четырехгранника брошены одновременно. Сколько бит информации будет нести сообщение о том, что один из четырехгранников упал на грань с цифрой 1 в то время, как второй четырехгранник упал на грань с цифрой 2. В ответе укажите целое число.

Я решил эту задачу так: `log(2)4 + log(2)4 = 4 бита`.

В чем ошибка? Почему это решение неправильное?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ, разумеется, другой. Ваше решение и решение [@teveakea](/users/2021/teveakea) верно, если условие понимать так, что первый четырехгранник дал 1, а второй - 2. А в условии написано **один** четырехгранник дал 1, **другой** - 2. Таким образом, подходят 2 из 16 результатов эксперимента (1, 2) и (2, 1). Ну, теперь считайте логарифм :)

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, подробно.

Comment: Один - необязательно первый, другой необязательно второй. Всего 16 исходов эксперимента, пар (X, Y), где X и Y - число от 1 до 4. Ваше решение использует только пару (1, 2), тогда как условие подразумевает любую пару (1, 2) или (2, 1). То есть вероятность выпадения заданного условием набора не 1/16, а 2/16.

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое, получается log(2)8 =3 бита, именно такой ответ и получился.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так: кодируем состояние одного четырехгранника битами

- выпало 1 - 0001
- выпало 2 - 0010
- выпало 3 - 0100
- выпало 4 - 1000

Теперь опишем событие 1 четырехгранник упал 1, а второй 2 = 00010010 - то есть 4 разрядами кодируем состояние одного четырехгранника.

Соответственно твое событие несет информации в 8 бит = 1 байт.

Comment: вообще хрень какаято, ответ близко не такой!